# How to extend object prototype created with anonymous function

Tags: javascript, ajax, oop, prototype

I'm using "scrollPagination" javascript for ajax pagination.
here is a code:

```
(function( $ ){
    $.fn.scrollFeedPagination = function(options) {
        var opts = $.extend($.fn.scrollFeedPagination.defaults, options);  
        var target = opts.scrollTarget;
        if (target == null){
            target = obj; 
        }
        opts.scrollTarget = target;

        return this.each(function() {
            $.fn.scrollFeedPagination.init($(this), opts);
        });
    };
    $.fn.stopScrollPagination = function(){
        return this.each(function() {
            $(this).attr('scrollPagination', 'disabled');
        });
    };
    $.fn.scrollFeedPagination.loadContent = function(obj, opts){
        console.log(opts);
        var target = opts.scrollTarget;
        var mayLoadContent = ($(target)[0].scrollHeight - $(target).scrollTop()) == $(target).height();
        if (mayLoadContent){
            if (opts.beforeLoad != null){
                opts.beforeLoad(); 
            }
            $(obj).children().attr('rel', 'loaded');
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: opts.contentPage,
                data: opts.contentData,
                success: function(data){
                    console.log(data);
                    console.log(1);
                    var selector = target.selector;
                    var response = $(data).find(selector).children();
                    $(obj).append(response);
                    var objectsRendered = $(obj).children('[rel!=loaded]');
                    if (opts.afterLoad != null){
                        opts.afterLoad(objectsRendered);    
                    }
                },
                dataType: 'html'
            });
        }
    };

    $.fn.scrollFeedPagination.init = function(obj, opts){
        var target = opts.scrollTarget;

        $(obj).attr('scrollPagination', 'enabled');
        $(target).scroll(function(event){
            if ($(obj).attr('scrollPagination') == 'enabled'){
                $.fn.scrollFeedPagination.loadContent(obj, opts);       
            }
            else {
                event.stopPropagation();    
            }
        });
        $.fn.scrollFeedPagination.loadContent(obj, opts);
    };
    $.fn.scrollFeedPagination.defaults = {
        'contentPage' : null,
        'contentData' : {},
        'beforeLoad': null,
        'afterLoad': null   ,
        'scrollTarget': null,
        'heightOffset': 0         
    };  
})( jQuery );
```

it work fine when I itialize it on one node.
but two nodes interfere with each other:

example:

```
node1.pagination({
'contentPage': ajaxurl,
    'contentData': {
         action: 'chat_pagination',
         'last_time' : last_time,
    },
    'scrollTarget': node1, 
    'beforeLoad': function() {},
    'afterLoad': function(elementsLoaded) {
        last_time = node1.children('div').last().data('last-id');
    }
});
```

it works but as soon as I initialize another one

```
node2.pagination({
'contentPage': ajaxurl,
    'contentData': {
         action: 'feeds_pagination',
         'last_time' : last_time,
    },
    'scrollTarget': node2, 
    'beforeLoad': function() {},
    'afterLoad': function(elementsLoaded) {
        last_time = node2.children('div').last().data('last-id');
    }
});
```

now node1 updates with last_time of node2 and ajax action also 'feeds_pagination'.

Now to solve this, I need to have two instances of scrollFeedPagination();
is it possible extend with syntax like this?

Comment: Where is your `last_time` variable declared? It seems to be your fault, not the library's one.

Comment: `last_time` is declared corectly, I just omitied that part for simplicity., does not matter, even if I send node2 with 'last_time2' it will have both, `last_time` and `last_time2`

Comment: Oh right, I though you were asking about `last_time` being updated incorrectly. I see your problem now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> var opts = $.extend($.fn.scrollFeedPagination.defaults, options);
> ```

Notice that the first parameter to [`$.extend`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/) is the object that is getting extended (with properties from the objects in the rest of the arguments), and is also the result of the function that is `return`ed. So you're basically setting

```
var opts = $.fn.scrollFeedPagination.defaults
// extend it then:
$.extend(opts, options);
```

As you can see, both your `opts` objects will be the same thing actually, and extending it the second time will overwrite the first configuration. Instead, start with a new empty object, and extend it first with the defaults and then the options parameter:

```
var opts = $.extend({}, $.fn.scrollFeedPagination.defaults, options);
```

Comment: shit I cant do it :D I tried many variations but never undestood how to start ) I declare `var options` which is everything I was writing inside scrollFeedPagination() and then I do     `var opts = $.extend({}, $.fn.scrollFeedPagination.defaults, options);`

Comment: oh, you mean I need to modify library?

Comment: I never managed to do it :( could you please update your answer with real example?

Comment: What do you mean by "real example"? The snippet matches your case perfectly.

Comment: perfectly jsFiddle, but, just to tell me where to put those would be great. sorry

Comment: I have read it many times, tried many combinations, no success

Comment: Just put the additional `{}, ` at your declaration of the `opts` variable.